# sampling below nyquist frequency

Tags: sampling

Can someone explain me that when we sample that sinusoid with a frequency below the Nyquist frequency (below half the sampling frequency), why we end up taking two samples per cycle of the sinusoid?

Comment: "Below" the nyquist frequency means fewer than two samples per sinewave cycle.

Comment: Nyquist states that you need to sample at _at least_ twice the maximum frequency of the signal if you are to have any hope of reconstructing the original signal. Fix your question.

Comment: Since Nyquist states that you need to sample at a frequency bigger than twice the signal, for any signal that complies with this request, there will be at least THREE samples for each period.

Comment: @ClaudioAviChami It means there will be >= 2 samples, e.g. 2.x samples where x can be rather small. A CD can reproduce 20kHz with a sampling frequency if 44.1kHz.

Comment: You are correct, there will be > 2 samples, not necessarily 3... but for sure not two.

Answer (score 4):

Nyquist gives you the minimum sampling rate so that you can determine the frequency of a periodic wave.

If you sample a sine wave at 0.75 Nyquist, you get a false sine wave as shown in black dashes.  This is called aliasing and it occurs at any frequency below Nyquist.

[image: 0.75 Nyquist]

At Nyquist, you can determine frequency, but not amplitude, of a sinewave as shown by the black dashes.

Almost all images of Nyquist on the web show sampling at the peak, which is almost impossible.  The following is a more appropriate representation.

[image: Nyquist]

Above Nyquist, it is possible to see frequency and amplitude of a periodic waveform by repeated samplings.  At 1.25 Nyquist:

[image]